# Make css specific for 404 error page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error component in react, which i want to render

The page works file, but in order for the component to displkay the content correctly, i have to apply some global css, to the body.

```
 body{
            background: #ff7300;
            color:#fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            max-height:700px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

If i use a wrapping div, it will not work properly.

The max height is not set properly, and my animations, only work when the global body css applies.

here are some examples of my animations:

```
        .x1_5{
            top:-80px;
            left:250px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
            -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
            transform: scale(0.3);
            -webkit-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite;
            -o-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite; 
        }

        .x2 {
            left: 250px;
            top:30px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
            -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
            transform: scale(0.6);
            opacity: 0.6; 
            -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
            -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
        }

        .x3 {
            left: 250px; bottom: -70px;

            -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
            -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
            transform: scale(0.6);
            opacity: 0.8; 

            -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;




    <div className="error">
    <div id="clouds">
    <div class="cloud x1"></div>
    <div class="cloud x1_5"></div>
    <div class="cloud x2"></div>
    <div class="cloud x3"></div>
    <div class="cloud x4"></div>
    <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>
<div class='c'>
    <div class='_404'>404</div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class='_1'>THE PAGE</div>
    <div class='_2'>WAS NOT FOUND</div>
    <a class='btn' href='#'><span>BACK TO SAFETY </span> 
</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with using, the body css, ais that it applies to my main component, where my 404 page is rendered.

Here is the react route, I'm rendering in my main App.js component

```
   <Switch>
    <Route path="*" exact={true} component={ErrorPage}> 
</Route>
    </Switch>
```

Is there a way, that i can make the css apply only when this component is rendered, or make it work with a wrapping html tag.

Comment: Use something like react-body-classname (npm-package). Then you can set a class to the body tag whenever this errorpage is rendered. Then apply the special css to only body.someTag

Comment: Is it a special query selector i Can apply in my JSX code?

Comment: Just google react-body-classname npm, read the docs. You can add tags wherever in your component tree, each level can add more classes to the body tag based on any condition you define